# Suggestions to indicate the second person pronoun "you" is singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, personal-pronouns

Do you have any suggestions to clearly show that the second person pronoun is singular, not simply basing it on context?  I would appreciate hearing your ideas!

Comment: In what situation would you not be able to base it on context where an error would have consequences?

Comment: Thou? Used to be second person singular.

Comment: @Jim Context may not be clear enough in situations where the context has both plural and singular subjects.  So my question is for when you wanted to make it absolutely clear whom you were addressing.

Comment: @Conrado  Right, it used to be easy with thou.  So I am wondering about modern ways of doing this.

Comment: @thinkpad22 - Yes, you’ve redescribed the general setup. I’m interested to hear about a *real* situation that you have in mind where you’d actually need this- a “for example” ...    in thinking about it I’ve decided it must be a verbal situation, because in a written situation, writing is either written to explicitly address the recipient (a letter) or it’s specifically written for a broad audience (a book, a road sign, a menu, etc).

Comment: @Jim  This could be a written situation.  For example, let's say one is writing a letter to a leader and his followers.  He starts by addressing the leader.  After that, he addresses the followers.  But then, the writer suddenly switches to addressing the leader with nothing in the context to indicate this switch, and he writes "You (leader) should listen very well."  So how can we clearly specify the leader with the second person pronoun "you" without adding extra meaning.  You guy?  You man?  You one?  Before it was easy with "thou."

Answer (score 4):

One way consists in using the pronoun "yourself" in an apposition.

- Are you, **yourself**, committed to the goal of taking  steps to end this situation?

There is the possibility of using a term of address.

- You, **Edward**, will go to the mountain and prepare the chalet.
- You, **Mister Hill**, are being congratulated by the manager.

Another way is the use of a special phrase, such as "**of all …**", but then something is added to the meaning; therefore, if this added meaning is relevant, there is no problem as you can kill two birds with one stone.

- You, **of all *the men in the group***, decided that this was the right thing to do.
- You, **alone**, are responsible.

Comment: In  _Are you, yourself, committed to the goal of taking steps to end this situation?_, "yourself" is not in apposition to "you" since it cannot stand in for the whole NP: we can't say *_Are yourself, committed to the goal of taking steps to end this situation?_

Comment: @BillJ I don't find this exact form using commas in CoGEL, yet there is this in it:: "subject - appositional phrase - ex: _We ourselves couldn't come." and "Anyone but you yourself would have noticed the change.". Is the addition of commas so abnormal? Moreover, I also find cases of use of the commas in the literature (4 in this page: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22are+you+yourself%22&lr=lang_en&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1en,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir1tjv5cbvAhXPxIUKHcozACEQpwUIJA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1).

Comment: See my first comment for the reason why it can't appositional.

Comment: @BillJ But the noun phrase is "you", (a pronoun can be the head of a NP), and "yourself" does stand for "you"!?

Comment: The reflexive "yourself" is a modifier within the structure of the larger NP "you yourself". It is not appositional but is used simply for **emphasis**. Appositional NPs serve to identify the head noun..

Comment: Google Books certainly has lots of examples of "you alone" without commas: "...in the end, you alone are dancing" (1996), "For you alone, I wait in a midnight sky of stars" (2015), "...of all mankind I love but you alone" (1867), "The main part pertains to you alone" (1896), "You alone are your own enemy" (1871) etc.